# Two forms in a single page and with Bootsrap modal using Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, codeigniter, modal-dialog

```js
$('#form1').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#emailModal').modal("show"); // open the modal
        });
     
     $(document).on('click','#sendEmail',function(){
         $('#UpdateEmailModal').modal("show"); // open the modal
      }
      });
      $(document).on('click','#UpdateSendEmail',function(){
          $('#form1method').submit();
      });

      $(document).on('click','#Update_Close',function(){
          $('#form2method').submit();
      });

      $(document).on('click','#Close',function(){
          window.location = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/page_method";
      });
```

```html
<!--Form 1-->

<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>mycontroller/method1" method="post" id="form1method">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="email" name="email">
<button type="submit" id="form1">Submit</button>
</form>

<!--Form 2 -->
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>mycontroller/method2" method="post" id="form2method">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="email" name="email">
<button type="submit" id="form2">Submit</form>
</form>

<!--Modal 1 -->
  <!--Email Modal -->
<div id="emailModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Send Email to User</h4> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
           <label class="col-md-3">To Email</label>
         <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_id" id="email_id" placeholder="Email ID">
          </div>
          <label class="col-md-3">Message</label>
          <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" id="sendEmail"><strong>Update</strong></button>
  <button  class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" id="Close"><strong>Close</strong></button>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Modal 2 -->
    <!--Email Status and Update Modal -->
<div id="UpdateEmailModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Update Form</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Click Submit to Update and Send Email (or) Click Cancel to Update</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" id="UpdateSendEmail"><strong>Submit</strong></button>  
  <button  class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" id="Update_Close"><strong>cancel</strong></button>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
enter code here
    <?php
    *//My Controller*
     public function method1(){
      $result = $this->model->update_model();
      if($result == true){
      $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","post_page");
      redirect("post_page");
    }}
    public function method2(){
     $result = $this->model->update_model2();
     if($result == true){
     $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","post_page");
     redirect("post_page");
   }}

   *`//My Model`*
   public function update_model(){
     $data = array(
      'name' => $this->input->post("name"),
      'email' => $this->input->post("email")
    );
     $this->db->update('user',$data);
    }

   public function update_model2(){
     $data = array(
      'name' => $this->input->post("name"),
      'email' => $this->input->post("email"),
      'status' => "1"
     );
   $this->db->update('user',$data);
    }
   ?>
```

When clicking edit form, edit page will open, in that i have two forms (Form1 and Form2). Only one form should appear in a page. When i click submit of Form1 a Modal1 will open and clicking Update button the Modal2 will open. Based on the two buttons(Submit and Cancel) in Modal2 a response should happen. Like if i click "Submit" method2 in Controller should execute or else if i click method1 should execute. How do do it in Controller?. I don;t know if i doing it correctly. If you guys have any idea to solve this, please help me out.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make each of your submit button with a different name. So when you press the submit button, like in the form1, `form1submit_btn`, the page reload and simply check the post input :

You button

```
<button type="submit" name="form1submit_btn" class="btn btn-info btn-block" id="sendEmail"><strong>Update</strong></button>
```

Both of your form action have the same action `action="<?base_url("myController/method")?>`, and you treat them directly in the controller :

```
function method(){
    //form 1 has been submit
    if($this->input->post("form1submit_btn")){

        $result = $this->model->update_model();
        if($result == true)
            $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","post_page");

    }

    //form 2 has been submit
    if($this->input->post("form2submit_btn")){

        $result = $this->model->update_model2();
        if($result == true)
            $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","post_page");

    }

    redirect("post_page");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but my problem is different, I want to show any one form in a page. For example, Form1 should show until i complete the update of name and email, then i want to show Form2, to update the status and close it. on Form2 , I want to open modal to send email to user but not in the Form1. Is there any condition to do like this.